# Reseting Vista Admin Password from Installation DIsk

Tags: windows-vista, password-recovery

I am trying to reset the admin account password that I forgot for an old Vista machine.  Because I don't have a password reset disk, I have resorted to attempting to run net user from the command line of the recovery environment on the vista install disk.  However, net user sees only the users (guest, administrator) from the live environment and refuses to recognize the users on my Vista install.  I am wondering if/how I can switch it so it sees the users on my local install?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean a Vista-created password reset disk. You don't really need that. You can go get the Ultimate Boot CD, and run the "Offline NT Password & Registry Editor" tool.

This will let you reset the password

> http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/